# "Debug info unavailable" and then can not interact with debugging session in Intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

As shown in the screenshot we are stopped at a breakpoint in java8 source code - specifically `ProcessBuilder`.

When attempting to view any variables we get

```
Debug info unavailable
```

Things get even worse however. Notice in the `variables` list that the entries for the `cmdarray` are listed.

[image]

I can not even copy their value.  When selecting `copy value` nothing gets placed into the clipboard.

This is a pretty serious problem - has anyone run into this and found a workaround?

I am on `IJ Ultimate 14.1.4`

Comment: Can you let us know what type of Java application this is (e.g. web, standalone, Android, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen standalone app

Comment: I tend to see this general type of error in IntelliJ when the source code becomes out of sync with the what is actually running.  Could you try invalidating cached and then restarting IntelliJ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My own source code is fine - breakpoints, watches and all. It is only the jdk source code exhibiting the behavior.